# How to retrieve image URL from Media Bundle field in Twig Template

Tags: theming, 8, media

I have created a custom media bundle using the [Media Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) module.
Here is a screen grab of the media bundle:

[image]

I have created a Twig template `media--image.twig.html`

I am able to retrieve all of the field values via the `content` variable in Twig but I'm having difficulty retrieving the `field_image` URL.

Here is a snapshot of the output from `{{ kint(content.field_image) }}`:

[image]

How do I extract the URL?  I can see a target Id, so presumably I can load the entity in the preprocess function and pass through the variable but I would've expected the full target object to be available within the Twig template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter)

> This module adds a url formatter for image field. Then you can output
> image url directly.

Enable the module, edit your image field, change the formatter to url.

Now `{{ content.field_image }}` will print the url instead of rendering the image.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  The only additional task was to override the `field--media--field-image--image.twig.html` template to remove the divs from the Image URL Formatter output.